# Restrict Solr data import to localhost, but allow select from any address

Tags: tomcat, solr

I currently have 2 machines on the same local network - one with Tomcat 7 and Solr 3.5, and the other with Apache and PHP. My PHP code gets search results via solrservername:8080/solr/corename/select?..., and I update the index by manually hitting .../dataimport?...

How can I restrict access to the dataimport URL (preferrably by only allowing it to be accessed from localhost) without affecting the select URL? To clarify, I would rather not mess with HTTPS or add HTTP authentication if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong but looks like there isn't a way to restrict the access like you want without using a proxy. You can have a look yourself at the [Tomcat Security FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Security#Q6) and referenced links, it doesn't seem possible to specify a url-pattern while allowing a specific ip.

The options are configuring Solr behind an Apache proxy and have all the flexibility you need, otherwise you can use simple http authentication (I know you wrote you don't want to, but it's pretty simple, I promise!) for the dataimport url modifying the solr `web.xml` like this:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>DataImport protection</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>DataImport</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/core/dataimport/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>solradmin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

and the `tomcat-users.xml` (within `$CATALINA_HOME/conf`) like this:

```
<role rolename="solradmin"/>
<user username="user" password="pass" roles="solradmin"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea of what I am usually doing in such cases: In Solr machine you could set a firewall blocking all incoming calls to port:80 and setup a reverse proxy (e.g. Apache server) to redirect all calls hitting solrservername/solr/corename/select?* to solrservername:8080/solr/corename/select?**. The rest will only be accessible locally.

Moreover, in solr security you can limit access to server based on ip address by putting the following in server.xml

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="127.0.0.1″/>
```